# Jamod slave example

Tags: java, master-slave, modbus

I need to make a program in Java using jamod or j2mod I'm searching for examples but I don't understand how it works.
I need to connect to an equipment with modbus support, for example if I send a string like "date" the equipment responses the date.
In the examples I read saw that with jamod send request and receive response but I dont understand where I can put the string "date".
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to know the specific register where you could send the date as a collection of Modbus register (16-bit) values.  You can't just send a string.

What you need to do is locate the "Modbus Map" for the device.  It will tell you the Modbus register addresses and their purposes.